# Match return substring between two substrings using regexp

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a list of records that are character vectors. Here's an example:

```
'1mil_0,1_1_1_lb200_ks_drivers_sorted.csv'
'1mil_0_1_lb100_ks_drivers_sorted.csv'
'1mil_1_1_lb2_100_100_ks_drivers_sorted.csv'
'1mil_1_1_lb100_ks_drivers_sorted.csv'
```

From these names I would like to extract whatever's between the two substrings `1mil_` and `_ks_drivers_sorted.csv`.

So in this case the output would be:

```
0,1_1_1_lb200
0_1_lb100
1_1_lb2_100_100
1_1_lb100
```

I'm using MATLAB so I thought to use `regexp` to do this, but I can't understand what kind of regular expression would be correct.

Or are there some other ways to do this without using `regexp`?

Comment: `1mil_(.*)_ks_drivers_sorted\.csv` and use captured group #1

Comment: @anubhava What do you mean by "use captured group #1"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the data be:

```
x = {'1mil_0,1_1_1_lb200_ks_drivers_sorted.csv'
     '1mil_0_1_lb100_ks_drivers_sorted.csv'
     '1mil_1_1_lb2_100_100_ks_drivers_sorted.csv'
     '1mil_1_1_lb100_ks_drivers_sorted.csv'};
```

You can use [lookbehind and lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find the two limiting substrings, and match everything in between:

```
result = cellfun(@(c) regexp(c, '(?<=1mil_).*(?=_ks_drivers_sorted\.csv)', 'match'), x);
```

Or, since the regular expression only produces one match, the following simpler alternative can be used (thanks [@excaza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2748311/excaza) for noticing):

```
result = regexp(x, '(?<=1mil_).*(?=_ks_drivers_sorted\.csv)', 'match', 'once');
```

In your example, either of the above gives

```
result =
  4×1 cell array
    '0,1_1_1_lb200'
    '0_1_lb100'
    '1_1_lb2_100_100'
    '1_1_lb100'
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: `result = regexp(x, '(?<=1mil_).*(?=_ks_drivers_sorted.csv)','match');  [result{:}].'` (if you want to avoid `cellfun`)

Comment: @SardarUsama Good idea. But I'm not sure that `result = [result{:}].'` is much clearer than `result = cellfun(@(c) ..., x)`

Comment: I agree with that though :)

Comment: @SardarUsama If you use `regexp` with `'once'` you don't need to denest the cells.

Answer (score 0):

For me the easy way to do this is just use espace or nothing to replace what you don't need in your string, and the rest is what you need.

If is a list, you can use a loop to do this.

Exemple to replace "1mil_" with "" and "_ks_drivers_sorted.csv" with ""

```
newChr = strrep(chr,'1mil_','')
newChr = strrep(chr,'_ks_drivers_sorted.csv','')
```